# Identify a green shard spell in Magicka

Tags: pc, magicka

Playing co-op I saw a wicked area of effect spell where large green glass-like shards shot up through the ground in a circle around the mage. How can I cast this or a similar spell? I forgot to ask the guy how he did it.

Obviously I shift-right click to get the area of effect, but I'm not sure what elements are involved. Life could account for the green, although the spell really hurt goblins and life would heal them. I will be able to recognize it from a picture.

Comment: Spikes sounds like earth-element.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer there were shards instead of spikes (same thing?) so I'm not convined that it was Earth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the spell you are looking for is Ice AoE cast, possibly with a life thrown in for the green color. This shows ice-looking shards spike up from the earth all around you, dealing a fair amount of AoE damage, enough to outdamage a single Life added to give it a green color.

Screenshot of 5xIce AoE cast [QRQRQRQRQR]
[image]

Comment: Adding in life does make it green. I must have mis-remembered exactly what it did, but thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like Life + Ice + Direct target (i.e., Right click, not shift right click. It's not technically an area spell, though it does fire in a frontal cone) - be careful, those shards actually HEAL non-undead targets.

Here's a pretty picture for you:[image: Ice+Life+Right Click]

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of Life doing that, but this seemed to hurt them ... maybe it's just the ultimate anti-undead spell :D can you post a picture?

Comment: Just double checked, and, yeah, it's definitely healing when used with life. Now, if you do use it as an Area spell, rather than a direct spell, it will both heal and do damage, based on the amount of life and ice used -  in general, it will do more damage than it heals for in this case, but the life element at that point does nothing other than reduce the overall effectiveness of your spell.

Comment: The other possibility is that you're misremembering the green color (or have your monitor miscalibrated or somesuch), and were just looking at an ordinary Ice spell, which has a blue-ish hue.

Comment: This is what [wqrqrqrqr](http://brian.baligad.name/2011/magicka-aoe-healshards.jpg) (heal+iceshards x4) shift + right click looks like. Not really green shards (even just wqr is the same color).

Comment: Looks sweet but they aren't coming up through the ground. Maybe I'm crazy and this spell doesn't exist :S

Comment: This is the closest I can find to what I saw, except I would AoE it. Hopefully someone will eventually find a perfect match for my description.